# Выравнивание блоков div: слева картинка, справа форма

Tags: wordpress, html, форма, связи

Всем привет столкнулся с такой проблемой как добиться такого результата как на стриншоте?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итак, сайт на котором хочу разместить, создан на wordpress. Форма на adobe muse.

Как мне добиться такого вида: слева - картинка, справа - форма, вся форма по центру страницы!

[Форма отправки сообщения находится на этой странице, может пригодиться кому-то](http://1.santehniki.pp.ua/vyzvat-santekhnika-kiev.html)

Вот что прописываю на странице:

```
<div class="blockotpravka">

<img class="imgotpravka" src="http://1.santehniki.pp.ua/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/stiralka-k-kanalizacii-1-1024x768.jpg" width="481" height="361">
<div class="otpravka">

[caldera_form id="CF58d1926c3410b"]

</div>
</div>
```

В стилях прописываю так, чтобы по центру было два блока

```
.blockotpravka {
widht: 100 %;
} 

.imgotpravka {
display: block;
margin: auto;
}

.otpravka { 
widht: 400px; 
margin: 0 auto; 
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`float` необходимо применить к картинке (к первому элементу)

```
.imgotpravka {
    ...
    float: left;
}
```

а `margin: 0 auto;` соответственно к общему блоку `.blockotpravka`

```css
.blockotpravka {
  width: 800px;
  margin:auto;
}

.imgotpravka {
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
}

.otpravka {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blockotpravka">

  <img class="imgotpravka" src="http://1.santehniki.pp.ua/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/stiralka-k-kanalizacii-1-1024x768.jpg" width="481" height="361">

  <div class="otpravka">[caldera_form id="CF58d1926c3410b"]</div>

</div>
```